# Is there a way to get the Skype logo in the cvtheme document class?

Tags: moderncv

I'm using the `cvtheme` document class and `\moderncv{classic}` to create a CV. The field I am applying for jobs in often conduct their interviews over Skype. The are command to get small phone (`phone`), cellphone (`\mobile`) and email (`\email`) logos. Would it be possible to add a small Skype logo in the same manner? This would be a lot more aestheically pleasing than having to have "Skype: *skypename*" in the final output.

Comment: Have you checked the copyrights for this logo first?

Comment: @LudovicC. No. Good point.

Comment: The current font awesome has the skype icon. It seems that the current LaTeX package hasn't been updated with the new icons. You should be able to do that yourself by installing (or copying) the new font file (otf) and using them with LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's included in the latest version of [font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). There is a LaTeX package for Font Awesome, but it doesn't include a command for the Skype logo, so you have to add it manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newcommand\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \faSkype{} Skype \\
    \faPhone{} Phone \\
    \faFacebookSign{} Facebook
\end{document}
```

[image: preview]

Another solution I can think of is manually accessing it. Here's how:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\fontawesome
    [ Path = /Path/to/font-awesome-4.0.1/fonts/ ,
      Extension = .otf ]
    {FontAwesome}
\newcommand\fasymbol[1]{{\fontawesome\symbol{"F#1}}}
\newcommand\faSkype{\fasymbol{17E}}
\newcommand\faPhone{\fasymbol{095}}
\newcommand\faFacebook{\fasymbol{082}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\faSkype{} Skype \\
\faPhone{} Phone \\
\faFacebook{} Facebook
\end{document}
```

For the symbol codes you can check [the cheatsheet](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) on their site. You'll find the icon name (eg: `fa-skype`) along with the hexadecimal unicode code for the symbol (eg: `&#xf17e;`). From the unicode code you can use the last three numbers/letters in capitals (`17E`) in the custom `\fasymbol` command. For this example I've created three macro's.

Comment: Concerning your first solution I cannot have skype icon while having added it manually. Also how could we have an icon for mobile?

Comment: @giannis: have you tried installing Font Awesome as a system font?

Comment: yes i have tried it, but still I have no result.

Comment: @giannis: In that case either try the second method or wait for an update.

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution found on the net and adapted to my needs, working on classic theme of `moderncv`:

Add to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=.7\baselineskip]{SK}{skype_gray.png}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\skypesocialsymbol}{   
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture] {\pgfuseimage{SK}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\newcommand*{\skype}[1]{\extrainfo{\skypesocialsymbol\space \space\space \href{skype:#1?add}{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

You have to place into your project directory a image of skype logo, here called `skype_gray.png`.
Now you can write:

```
\skype{yourskypename}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.