# Font Awesome Skype icon doesn't work with moderncv

Tags: xetex, moderncv, fontawesome

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and XeLaTeX. Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman,english]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{Courier New}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\setotherlanguage[variant=us]{english}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}
\newcommand\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Smith}
\title{TeX writer}
\extrainfo{\faSkype~ myskypelogin}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Skype Font Awesome symbol has been created like in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141176/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-skype-logo-in-the-cvtheme-document-class). But for some strange reason it doen't work properly:
[image: result]

What am I doing wrong? I have tried to replace "F17E with "F117 and it worked just fine.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? Update the font. Get the new otf from the fontawesome webpage. Btw: Don>'t load xunicode before xltxtra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font `FontAwesome.otf` in TeX Live (January 2014) has version 3.1.0:

```bash
$ otfinfo --font-version $(kpsewhich FontAwesome.otf)
Version 3.1.0 2013
```

However [`icons.yml`](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/raw/master/src/icons.yml) shows that the glyph `Skype` was created in version 3.2:

```
- name:       Skype
  id:         skype
  unicode:    f17e
  created:    3.2
  categories:
    - Brand Icons
```

The current version of FontAwesome is 4.0.3.
It can be downloaded from the [project home page](http://fontawesome.io/).

Then the following LaTeX code should do:

```
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\providecommand\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}
```

### Which font file is found by XeTeX?

XeTeX writes an extended DVI format that is converted by `xdvipdfmx` to PDF.
If the latter program gets option `-v` (be verbose), then it prints the location of the font files that are used by it. Options can be passed to `xdvipdfmx` via option `-output-driver` of XeTeX:

```bash
xelatex "-output-driver=xdvipdfmx -v" test
```

Then the found font file with path is printed on the console.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, it doesn't work either.  I'm not using TeX Live and have the latest version of FontAwesome. Also I have checked in some WYSIWYG-editors that the Skype symbol exists in the font.

Comment: @VladimirPanchenko: Perhaps you have the font twice and the wrong version is found and used by XeTeX.

Comment: I tried to unistall all Font Awesome fonts and install last version again. It didn't help at all.

Comment: @VladimirPanchenko: You have to search for different font files. The font might be installed in the system *and* in the TeX installation. Installing a new version will not help, if there is an older version lying around to be found by XeTeX.

Comment: Thank you, old font file in MiKTeX folder was the problem!