# Skype Icon in the CV template?

Tags: graphics, symbols, moderncv

I'm trying to add the Skype icon in my CV, but it is not working. I am using Miktex 2.9 and WinEdt 8.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} 
\newcommand{\ingreen}[1]{{\color{blue}#1}}

\firstname{\textsc{S}} % Your first name
\familyname{\textsc{K}} % Your last name

\address{}{}
\mobile{(+00 000) 0000}
\phone{(+00 00) 0000}
\fax{(000) 111 1113}
\skype{SK}
\email{abc@gmail.com}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A quick search brings up this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141176/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-skype-logo-in-the-cvtheme-document-class

Comment: #DG' It's not working in Modern CV.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I followed the procedure described in [Creating Logo with Fancy Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145227/5764) to create the [S-logo](http://www.skype.com/en/legal/brand-guidelines/) as a vector graphic:

[image]

Now you can add a `\skype` command to the [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) interface, specifically the `casual` theme:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\skypesocialsymbol}{\includegraphics[height=.7\baselineskip]{skype_gray}}
\collectionadd[skype]{socials}{ SK}
\makeatother
```

Your header should resemble (taken from [`template.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex)):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'banking', 'oldstyle' and 'fancy'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'black', 'blue' (default), 'burgundy', 'green', 'grey', 'orange', 'purple' and 'red'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\skypesocialsymbol}{\includegraphics[height=.7\baselineskip]{skype_gray}}
\collectionadd[skype]{socials}{ SK}
\makeatother

...
```

Comment: I've simply copied and pasted your code into my TeXmaker installation and I get the following errors:

line 5:  ! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \makecvtitlenamewidth l.5 \setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}
line 6: ! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again> \par
line 6: ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). <to be read again> \par
line 14: ! LaTeX Error: \makecvfooter undefined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help....l.14 \renewcommand*{\makecvfooter}

It has to be a mistake in my settings. Any help appreciated.

Comment: @Michael: I've updated the answer to accommodate the latest updates of [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv).

Answer (score 9):

Just the symbol:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}    

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.08em,x=0.08em,xscale=0.25,yscale=-0.25, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\path[fill=black,even odd rule] (487.6550,288.9690) .. controls (489.0610,278.5690) and
  (489.8700,267.9960) .. (489.8700,257.2330) .. controls (489.8700,128.0770) and
  (384.5990,23.3610) .. (254.7670,23.3610) .. controls (241.8630,23.3610) and
  (229.2120,24.4210) .. (216.9010,26.4410) .. controls (194.8280,12.0570) and
  (168.5590,3.6740) .. (140.2880,3.6740) .. controls (62.7660,3.6740) and
  (0.0000,66.4820) .. (0.0000,143.9800) .. controls (0.0000,172.1780) and
  (8.2990,198.3740) .. (22.5900,220.3690) .. controls (20.6650,232.3860) and
  (19.6810,244.6920) .. (19.6810,257.2290) .. controls (19.6810,386.4050) and
  (124.8980,491.1100) .. (254.7660,491.1100) .. controls (269.4230,491.1100) and
  (283.6930,489.6840) .. (297.5620,487.1780) .. controls (319.1120,500.5470) and
  (344.4960,508.3260) .. (371.7080,508.3260) .. controls (449.2100,508.3260) and
  (512.0010,445.5020) .. (512.0010,368.0120) .. controls (511.9980,338.7190) and
  (503.0410,311.4840) .. (487.6550,288.9690) -- cycle(276.7400,429.5960) ..
  controls (202.0340,433.4870) and (167.0750,416.9590) .. (135.0500,386.9050) ..
  controls (99.2850,353.3370) and (113.6520,315.0500) .. (142.7900,313.1040) ..
  controls (171.9120,311.1590) and (189.3980,346.1160) .. (204.9410,355.8400) ..
  controls (220.4650,365.5280) and (279.5340,387.6000) .. (310.7350,351.9320) ..
  controls (344.7100,313.1040) and (288.1410,293.0120) .. (246.6760,286.9300) ..
  controls (187.4730,278.1640) and (112.7260,246.1370) .. (118.5410,183.0230) ..
  controls (124.3580,119.9490) and (172.1230,87.6090) .. (222.3910,83.0470) ..
  controls (286.4680,77.2300) and (328.1820,92.7540) .. (361.1760,120.9070) ..
  controls (399.3270,153.4360) and (378.6840,189.8010) .. (354.3770,192.7270) ..
  controls (330.1660,195.6360) and (302.9730,139.2230) .. (249.5860,138.3750) ..
  controls (194.5590,137.5110) and (157.3690,195.6360) .. (225.3000,212.1590) ..
  controls (293.2660,228.6640) and (366.0500,235.4450) .. (392.2610,297.5760) ..
  controls (418.4900,359.7130) and (351.5070,425.7010) .. (276.7400,429.5960) --
  cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now embedded in to the CV:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}

\firstname{\textsc{S}} % Your first name
\familyname{\textsc{K}} % Your last name

\newcommand*{\skypesymbol} {%
  \protect\raisebox{-0.085em}{%
\protect\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.08em,x=0.08em,xscale=0.022,yscale=-0.022, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\protect\path[fill=color2,even odd rule] (487.6550,288.9690) .. controls (489.0610,278.5690) and
  (489.8700,267.9960) .. (489.8700,257.2330) .. controls (489.8700,128.0770) and
  (384.5990,23.3610) .. (254.7670,23.3610) .. controls (241.8630,23.3610) and
  (229.2120,24.4210) .. (216.9010,26.4410) .. controls (194.8280,12.0570) and
  (168.5590,3.6740) .. (140.2880,3.6740) .. controls (62.7660,3.6740) and
  (0.0000,66.4820) .. (0.0000,143.9800) .. controls (0.0000,172.1780) and
  (8.2990,198.3740) .. (22.5900,220.3690) .. controls (20.6650,232.3860) and
  (19.6810,244.6920) .. (19.6810,257.2290) .. controls (19.6810,386.4050) and
  (124.8980,491.1100) .. (254.7660,491.1100) .. controls (269.4230,491.1100) and
  (283.6930,489.6840) .. (297.5620,487.1780) .. controls (319.1120,500.5470) and
  (344.4960,508.3260) .. (371.7080,508.3260) .. controls (449.2100,508.3260) and
  (512.0010,445.5020) .. (512.0010,368.0120) .. controls (511.9980,338.7190) and
  (503.0410,311.4840) .. (487.6550,288.9690) -- cycle(276.7400,429.5960) ..
  controls (202.0340,433.4870) and (167.0750,416.9590) .. (135.0500,386.9050) ..
  controls (99.2850,353.3370) and (113.6520,315.0500) .. (142.7900,313.1040) ..
  controls (171.9120,311.1590) and (189.3980,346.1160) .. (204.9410,355.8400) ..
  controls (220.4650,365.5280) and (279.5340,387.6000) .. (310.7350,351.9320) ..
  controls (344.7100,313.1040) and (288.1410,293.0120) .. (246.6760,286.9300) ..
  controls (187.4730,278.1640) and (112.7260,246.1370) .. (118.5410,183.0230) ..
  controls (124.3580,119.9490) and (172.1230,87.6090) .. (222.3910,83.0470) ..
  controls (286.4680,77.2300) and (328.1820,92.7540) .. (361.1760,120.9070) ..
  controls (399.3270,153.4360) and (378.6840,189.8010) .. (354.3770,192.7270) ..
  controls (330.1660,195.6360) and (302.9730,139.2230) .. (249.5860,138.3750) ..
  controls (194.5590,137.5110) and (157.3690,195.6360) .. (225.3000,212.1590) ..
  controls (293.2660,228.6640) and (366.0500,235.4450) .. (392.2610,297.5760) ..
  controls (418.4900,359.7130) and (351.5070,425.7010) .. (276.7400,429.5960) --
  cycle;
\protect\end{tikzpicture}}%
  ~}

\makeatletter
% defines one's email (optional)
% usage: \email{<email adress>}
\newcommand*{\skype}[1]{\def\@skype{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\makecvfooter}{%
  \setlength{\footerwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox[b]{\footerwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \color{color2}\addressfont%
        \vspace{\baselineskip}% forces a white line to ensure space between main text and footer (as footer height can't be known in advance)
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
          \flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}%
        \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
          \addtofooter{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofooter{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofooter{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@skype}}{}{\addtofooter{\skypesymbol\@skype}}%
        \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
          \addtofooter{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofooter{\@extrainfo}}%
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\footerboxwidth=0pt}}{}{\flushfooter}% the lengthtest is required to avoid flushing an empty footer, which could cause a blank line due to the \\ after the address, if no other personal info is used
        }}}%
  \pagestyle{plain}}
\makeatother

\address{}{}
\mobile{(+00 000) 0000}
\phone{(+00 00) 0000}
\fax{(000) 111 1113}
\skype{SK}
\email{abc@gmail.com}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Another option:

1. Download the latest version of the font from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome-4.0.3.zip
2. Replace the file

   ```
   texmf\fonts\opentype\public\fontawesome\FontAwesome.otf
   ```

   with the one contained in the `.zip` file.
3. Use

   ```
   \social[skype]{SK}
   ```

   to print your Skype account.

Try the following MWE (run with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\newcommand\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}
\newcommand*{\skypesocialsymbol}{\faSkype~}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\social}{O{}O{}m}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}%
    {%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{linkedin}}{\collectionadd[linkedin]{socials}{\protect\httplink[#3]{www.linkedin.com/in/#3}}}{}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{twitter}} {\collectionadd[twitter]{socials} {\protect\httplink[#3]{www.twitter.com/#3}}}    {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{github}}  {\collectionadd[github]{socials}  {\protect\httplink[#3]{www.github.com/#3}}}     {}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{skype}}   {\collectionadd[skype]{socials}   {#3}}                                           {}%
    }
    {\collectionadd[#1]{socials}{\protect\httplink[#3]{#2}}}}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}
\newcommand{\ingreen}[1]{{\color{blue}#1}}

\firstname{\textsc{S}} % Your first name
\familyname{\textsc{K}} % Your last name

\address{}{}
\mobile{(+00 000) 0000}
\phone{(+00 00) 0000}
\fax{(000) 111 1113}
\social[skype]{SK}
\email{abc@gmail.com}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to use the mobile phone symbol in `pdfLaTeX`?

Comment: @MarioS.E. Unfortunately the font is in `.otf` format, so the answer is no.