# ModernCV Pdflatex Skype logo issue

Tags: moderncv

I am using modernCV to build my CV along with pdflatex i wanted to add a skype logo to that.So on my first search i found that the easy way is to use fontawesome along with XeLaTeX but when i tried to use XeLatex all my resume changed to text without any graphics so i avoided that.
From this thread [Skype Icon in the CV template?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172191/skype-icon-in-the-cv-template)

```
\newcommand*{\skypesymbol} {%
  \protect\raisebox{-0.085em}{%
\protect\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.08em,x=0.08em,xscale=0.022,yscale=-0.022, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\protect\path[fill=color2,even odd rule] (487.6550,288.9690) .. controls (489.0610,278.5690) and
  (489.8700,267.9960) .. (489.8700,257.2330) .. controls (489.8700,128.0770) and
  (384.5990,23.3610) .. (254.7670,23.3610) .. controls (241.8630,23.3610) and
  (229.2120,24.4210) .. (216.9010,26.4410) .. controls (194.8280,12.0570) and
  (168.5590,3.6740) .. (140.2880,3.6740) .. controls (62.7660,3.6740) and
  (0.0000,66.4820) .. (0.0000,143.9800) .. controls (0.0000,172.1780) and
  (8.2990,198.3740) .. (22.5900,220.3690) .. controls (20.6650,232.3860) and
  (19.6810,244.6920) .. (19.6810,257.2290) .. controls (19.6810,386.4050) and
  (124.8980,491.1100) .. (254.7660,491.1100) .. controls (269.4230,491.1100) and
  (283.6930,489.6840) .. (297.5620,487.1780) .. controls (319.1120,500.5470) and
  (344.4960,508.3260) .. (371.7080,508.3260) .. controls (449.2100,508.3260) and
  (512.0010,445.5020) .. (512.0010,368.0120) .. controls (511.9980,338.7190) and
  (503.0410,311.4840) .. (487.6550,288.9690) -- cycle(276.7400,429.5960) ..
  controls (202.0340,433.4870) and (167.0750,416.9590) .. (135.0500,386.9050) ..
  controls (99.2850,353.3370) and (113.6520,315.0500) .. (142.7900,313.1040) ..
  controls (171.9120,311.1590) and (189.3980,346.1160) .. (204.9410,355.8400) ..
  controls (220.4650,365.5280) and (279.5340,387.6000) .. (310.7350,351.9320) ..
  controls (344.7100,313.1040) and (288.1410,293.0120) .. (246.6760,286.9300) ..
  controls (187.4730,278.1640) and (112.7260,246.1370) .. (118.5410,183.0230) ..
  controls (124.3580,119.9490) and (172.1230,87.6090) .. (222.3910,83.0470) ..
  controls (286.4680,77.2300) and (328.1820,92.7540) .. (361.1760,120.9070) ..
  controls (399.3270,153.4360) and (378.6840,189.8010) .. (354.3770,192.7270) ..
  controls (330.1660,195.6360) and (302.9730,139.2230) .. (249.5860,138.3750) ..
  controls (194.5590,137.5110) and (157.3690,195.6360) .. (225.3000,212.1590) ..
  controls (293.2660,228.6640) and (366.0500,235.4450) .. (392.2610,297.5760) ..
  controls (418.4900,359.7130) and (351.5070,425.7010) .. (276.7400,429.5960) --
  cycle;
\protect\end{tikzpicture}}%
  ~}

\makeatletter
% defines one's email (optional)
% usage: \email{<email adress>}
\newcommand*{\skype}[1]{\def\@skype{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\makecvfooter}{%
  \setlength{\footerwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox[b]{\footerwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \color{color2}\addressfont%
        \vspace{\baselineskip}% forces a white line to ensure space between main text and footer (as footer height can't be known in advance)
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
          \flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}%
        \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
          \addtofooter{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofooter{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofooter{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@skype}}{}{\addtofooter{\skypesymbol\@skype}}%
        \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
          \addtofooter{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofooter{\@extrainfo}}%
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\footerboxwidth=0pt}}{}{\flushfooter}% the lengthtest is required to avoid flushing an empty footer, which could cause a blank line due to the \\ after the address, if no other personal info is used
        }}}%
  \pagestyle{plain}}
\makeatother
```

i understood that adding this will bring a skypelogo to footer but this didnt work with my tex file. The threads example brings skype logo to footer and i dont want logo at footer.

My template looks like this

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                 % optional argument are 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'red', 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}
% personal data
 \newcommand*{\skypesymbol} {%
      \protect\raisebox{-0.085em}{%
    \protect\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.08em,x=0.08em,xscale=0.022,yscale=-0.022, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \protect\path[fill=color2,even odd rule] (487.6550,288.9690) .. controls (489.0610,278.5690) and
      (489.8700,267.9960) .. (489.8700,257.2330) .. controls (489.8700,128.0770) and
      (384.5990,23.3610) .. (254.7670,23.3610) .. controls (241.8630,23.3610) and
      (229.2120,24.4210) .. (216.9010,26.4410) .. controls (194.8280,12.0570) and
      (168.5590,3.6740) .. (140.2880,3.6740) .. controls (62.7660,3.6740) and
      (0.0000,66.4820) .. (0.0000,143.9800) .. controls (0.0000,172.1780) and
      (8.2990,198.3740) .. (22.5900,220.3690) .. controls (20.6650,232.3860) and
      (19.6810,244.6920) .. (19.6810,257.2290) .. controls (19.6810,386.4050) and
      (124.8980,491.1100) .. (254.7660,491.1100) .. controls (269.4230,491.1100) and
      (283.6930,489.6840) .. (297.5620,487.1780) .. controls (319.1120,500.5470) and
      (344.4960,508.3260) .. (371.7080,508.3260) .. controls (449.2100,508.3260) and
      (512.0010,445.5020) .. (512.0010,368.0120) .. controls (511.9980,338.7190) and
      (503.0410,311.4840) .. (487.6550,288.9690) -- cycle(276.7400,429.5960) ..
      controls (202.0340,433.4870) and (167.0750,416.9590) .. (135.0500,386.9050) ..
      controls (99.2850,353.3370) and (113.6520,315.0500) .. (142.7900,313.1040) ..
      controls (171.9120,311.1590) and (189.3980,346.1160) .. (204.9410,355.8400) ..
      controls (220.4650,365.5280) and (279.5340,387.6000) .. (310.7350,351.9320) ..
      controls (344.7100,313.1040) and (288.1410,293.0120) .. (246.6760,286.9300) ..
      controls (187.4730,278.1640) and (112.7260,246.1370) .. (118.5410,183.0230) ..
      controls (124.3580,119.9490) and (172.1230,87.6090) .. (222.3910,83.0470) ..
      controls (286.4680,77.2300) and (328.1820,92.7540) .. (361.1760,120.9070) ..
      controls (399.3270,153.4360) and (378.6840,189.8010) .. (354.3770,192.7270) ..
      controls (330.1660,195.6360) and (302.9730,139.2230) .. (249.5860,138.3750) ..
      controls (194.5590,137.5110) and (157.3690,195.6360) .. (225.3000,212.1590) ..
      controls (293.2660,228.6640) and (366.0500,235.4450) .. (392.2610,297.5760) ..
      controls (418.4900,359.7130) and (351.5070,425.7010) .. (276.7400,429.5960) --
      cycle;
    \protect\end{tikzpicture}}%
      ~}

    \makeatletter
    % defines one's email (optional)
    % usage: \email{<email adress>}
    \newcommand*{\skype}[1]{\def\@skype{#1}}
    \renewcommand*{\makecvfooter}{%
      \setlength{\footerwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
      \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
        \fancyfoot[c]{%
          \parbox[b]{\footerwidth}{%
            \centering%
            \color{color2}\addressfont%
            \vspace{\baselineskip}% forces a white line to ensure space between main text and footer (as footer height can't be known in advance)
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
              \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
              \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%
              \flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}%
            \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
              \addtofooter{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofooter{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofooter{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@skype}}{}{\addtofooter{\skypesymbol\@skype}}%
            \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
              \addtofooter{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofooter{\@extrainfo}}%
            \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\footerboxwidth=0pt}}{}{\flushfooter}% the lengthtest is required to avoid flushing an empty footer, which could cause a blank line due to the \\ after the address, if no other personal info is used
            }}}%
      \pagestyle{plain}}
    \makeatother

% personal data
\firstname{Ganesh}
\familyname{H}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{KNRA, DVVV,TVVV}{KKKK, IIIIIa - 695789}
\email{xxx@gmail.com}
\skype{DD}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

How can i bring logo of skype under that email id's symbol.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Your example has a lot of surplus code in it.  Try to whittle it down so that it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: I copied the code from that thread and am not that much of at Tex guy to strip it down :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `\extrainfo` command; as in, instead of `\skype{DD}`, put in:

```
\extrainfo{\skypesymbol DD}
```

This seems to be precisely the purpose of the `\extrainfo` command.

[image: Skype logo in header]

Comment: I tird changing the order of email and skype but its not working can you give me a fix?                                                                                                          \extrainfo{\skypesymbol DD}                                                       \email{xxx@gmail.com}