# Skype icon on moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I am using moderncv with classic style.

I wrote my personal info on the top of the page, precisely on the left of my picture. I need to write my linkedln and skype account in the same line so as not to overcome one page for my CV.
How can I create skype icon ?
How can I write both the info of linkedln and skype on the same line with a short space in the middle?

Thank you

**Edit** Since the OP was not able to add the code from the comment, I do it for him/her in this 'outstanding' case. (C.Hupfer)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} \moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.5cm, bottom=0.5cm, left=1cm, right=1cm,nofoot]{geometry} 
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{35}{80}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\fontsize{15}{80}\mdseries\upshape}
\firstname{V} 
\familyname{M} 
\title{Curriculum Vit\ae{}} 
\address{xxxx}{xxxx} 
\mobile{xxxx} 
\email{xxx}
\social[linkedin]{xxxx} %NOW HERE I WOULD LIKE TO ADD SKYPE ON THE SAME LINE 
 \extrainfo{Born in XXX (XXX), on June XX, XXX \\ Car owner, License Drive A, B} %\photo[60pt][0.4pt]{pictures/Fototessera_3} \begin{document} \vspace*{-15.5mm} 
\makecvtitle \vspace*{-11.7mm} \hrulefill \hspace{2pt} 
\today 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172191/skype-icon-in-the-cv-template

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please use the search text field in order to look whether there already questions (and hopefully answers too) connected to your request

Comment: Partially, but how can I modify my body program to let the programm to run? How can I put both linkedln and skype on the same line?

Comment: In the linked question, there are also links to other questions, for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141176/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-skype-logo-in-the-cvtheme-document-class

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My suggests are to follow the guidelines presented in [Skype Icon in the CV template?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172191/5764) in order to obtain a viable S-Logo symbol. Then include the LinkedIn *and* Skype symbols as part of the `\extrainfo` content where you have more control over the placement of things:

```
\newsavebox{\skypeicon}
\savebox{\skypeicon}{\includegraphics[height=.8\baselineskip]{example-image}}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172191/5764
\newcommand{\skypesocialsymbol}{\usebox{\skypeicon}}

\extrainfo{\linkedinsocialsymbol~XXXX \quad \skypesocialsymbol~XXXX \\
  Born in XXX (XXX), on June XX, XXX \\ Car owner, License Drive A, B} %
```

In the above code snippet, there is no usage of `\social` and `\skypeicon` relies on getting an image from the linked post.

[image]

---

Here is an example using [a `tikz` approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172295/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.5cm, bottom=0.5cm, left=1cm, right=1cm,nofoot]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{35}{80}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\fontsize{15}{80}\mdseries\upshape}

\firstname{V} % Your first name
\familyname{M} % Your last name

\newcommand*{\skypesocialsymbol} {%
  \protect\raisebox{-0.085em}{%
\protect\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.08em,x=0.08em,xscale=0.022,yscale=-0.022, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\protect\path[fill=color2,even odd rule] (487.6550,288.9690) .. controls (489.0610,278.5690) and
  (489.8700,267.9960) .. (489.8700,257.2330) .. controls (489.8700,128.0770) and
  (384.5990,23.3610) .. (254.7670,23.3610) .. controls (241.8630,23.3610) and
  (229.2120,24.4210) .. (216.9010,26.4410) .. controls (194.8280,12.0570) and
  (168.5590,3.6740) .. (140.2880,3.6740) .. controls (62.7660,3.6740) and
  (0.0000,66.4820) .. (0.0000,143.9800) .. controls (0.0000,172.1780) and
  (8.2990,198.3740) .. (22.5900,220.3690) .. controls (20.6650,232.3860) and
  (19.6810,244.6920) .. (19.6810,257.2290) .. controls (19.6810,386.4050) and
  (124.8980,491.1100) .. (254.7660,491.1100) .. controls (269.4230,491.1100) and
  (283.6930,489.6840) .. (297.5620,487.1780) .. controls (319.1120,500.5470) and
  (344.4960,508.3260) .. (371.7080,508.3260) .. controls (449.2100,508.3260) and
  (512.0010,445.5020) .. (512.0010,368.0120) .. controls (511.9980,338.7190) and
  (503.0410,311.4840) .. (487.6550,288.9690) -- cycle(276.7400,429.5960) ..
  controls (202.0340,433.4870) and (167.0750,416.9590) .. (135.0500,386.9050) ..
  controls (99.2850,353.3370) and (113.6520,315.0500) .. (142.7900,313.1040) ..
  controls (171.9120,311.1590) and (189.3980,346.1160) .. (204.9410,355.8400) ..
  controls (220.4650,365.5280) and (279.5340,387.6000) .. (310.7350,351.9320) ..
  controls (344.7100,313.1040) and (288.1410,293.0120) .. (246.6760,286.9300) ..
  controls (187.4730,278.1640) and (112.7260,246.1370) .. (118.5410,183.0230) ..
  controls (124.3580,119.9490) and (172.1230,87.6090) .. (222.3910,83.0470) ..
  controls (286.4680,77.2300) and (328.1820,92.7540) .. (361.1760,120.9070) ..
  controls (399.3270,153.4360) and (378.6840,189.8010) .. (354.3770,192.7270) ..
  controls (330.1660,195.6360) and (302.9730,139.2230) .. (249.5860,138.3750) ..
  controls (194.5590,137.5110) and (157.3690,195.6360) .. (225.3000,212.1590) ..
  controls (293.2660,228.6640) and (366.0500,235.4450) .. (392.2610,297.5760) ..
  controls (418.4900,359.7130) and (351.5070,425.7010) .. (276.7400,429.5960) --
  cycle;
\protect\end{tikzpicture}}%
  ~}

\title{Curriculum Vit\ae{}}
\address{xxxx}{xxxx}
\mobile{xxxx}
\email{xxx}
\extrainfo{\linkedinsocialsymbol~XXXX \quad \skypesocialsymbol~XXXX \\
  Born in XXX (XXX), on June XX, XXX \\ Car owner, License Drive A, B}
%\photo[60pt][0.4pt]{pictures/Fototessera_3}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{-15.5mm}
\makecvtitle % Print the CV title
\vspace*{-11.7mm}
\hrulefill \hspace{2pt} \today
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you can use the `fontawesome` package. Fontawesome is a free font that contains many web  symbols and the package eases its use. Unfortunately, the present version  is based on version 3 of the fonts, and the `Skype` symbol appeared in version 4. So I made a macro to have access to it, with a `faSkype` command? You'll only have, in addition, to download the latest version of the fonts (4.1.0) from [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), extract `fontawesome.otf` to your local texmf root, in `./fonts/otf` and finally run `texhash`(TeX Live) or Refresh FNDB (MiKTeX).

Here is a code as an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\def\faSkype{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}

\begin{document}
This is the Skype symbol in the \emph{Fontawesome} font:

\begin{center}\Large
\color{CadetBlue1}\faSkype
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how to add the skype icon in europass cv. fontawesome font is not working

Comment: Are you compiling  with `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`?

Comment: I am working from last one month ans still its not working.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241885/how-to-add-the-skype-icon-in-europass-cv

Comment: This doesn't tell me what is your compiler!

Comment: Me using LaTeX Compiler

Comment: @Micky K: Also, did you install the latest version of the font?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25825/discussion-between-bernard-and-micky-k).

Answer (score 0):

On this argument I have an updated solution regarding the installation of the fontawesome.otf file ([fontawesome.otf file download](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)). Indeed it needs to be put to your local texmf root, in ./fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/ and first you need to install the fontawesome sty file from the MikTex Package Manager (If you are using it). Onece this is done you also need to refresh the FNDB from the MikteX settings.

Moreover always remember to compile with XeLatex or LuaLatex. At the end of the story a simple code like this one should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newcommand\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \faSkype{} Skype \\
    \faPhone{} Phone \\
    \faFacebookSign{} Facebook
\end{document}
```

For the symbol codes you can check the [cheatsheet](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) on the fontawesome site. You'll find the icon name (eg: fa-skype) along with the hexadecimal unicode code for the symbol (eg: ). From the unicode code you can use the last three numbers/letters in capitals (17E) in the custom \fasymbol command.