# How to add the Skype ICON in Europass CV?

Tags: cv, europecv

How to add the Skype ICON in Euro-pass CV?

```
 \documentclass[helvetica,english,logo,notitle,totpages,utf8]{europecv2013}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[a4paper,top=1.2cm,left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[italian]{babel}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

 \ecvname{Name }
 \ecvaddress{House No }
 \ecvtelephone[+00000000]{+00000000}
 \ecvemail{abd@gmail.com}
 \ecvlinkedin{\href{http://ae.linkedin.com/pub/abc}{ae.linkedin.com/pub/abc /32/2aa/a83/}}
 \ecvgender{Male}
 \ecvnationality{name of country}
 \ecvdateofbirth{21 January 1974}
 \ecvbeforepicture{\ecvspace{-0.8cm}}
 \ecvpicture[height=3.5cm, width=3cm]{abc }
%\ecvafterpicture{\ecvspace{4.0cm}}

 \ecvfootnote{Â© European Union, 2002-2013 | http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu}
 %\ecvbeforepicture{\raggedleft}
 %\ecvpicture[width=2.5cm]{fototessera}
 %\ecvafterpicture{\ecvspace{-37mm}}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{europecv}
\ecvpersonalinfo[10pt]

\ecvposition{Job applied for}{ }

\ecvsection{Work experience}

\ecvworkexperience{September 2009 -- September 2012}{ Research  Assistant}{Abc University}{city}{}

%\ecvworkexperience{March 2002 -- July 2002}{Internship}{European Commission, Youth Unit, DG Education and Culture}{}

 %\ecvworkexperience{October 2001 â€“ February 2002}{Researcher / Independent Consultant}{Council of Europe, Budapest (Hungary)}{}{}

  \ecvsection{Education and training}

    \ecveducation{2005 -- 2008}{Master of Science }{Abc University,City }{Thesis Title: }{}

  \ecveducation{2001 -- 2005}{Bachelor of Science }{Abc City}{Studies focused }{}

 \ecvsection{Thesis Abstract}
 \ecvitem{Thesis Abstract:}{The thesis describes}

   \ecvsection{Research Interest}
  \ecveducation{}{}{ Computational Fluid Dynamics}{}{}

 \ecvsection{Personal skills}

  \ecvmothertongue[20pt]{English, German}
  \ecvlanguageheader
  \ecvlanguage{English}{C1}{C2}{C1}{C2}{C1}
  %\ecvlastlanguage{German}{A2}{A2}{A2}{A2}{A2}
  \ecvlanguagefooter[10pt]

  %\ecvitem[10pt]{Communication skills}{}


    \ecvitem[10pt]{Computer skills}{\LaTeX, Tikz, jPicEdt, Matlab, Mathematica, C/C++, \LaTeX Draw, Mayura Draw, MS Office.}

     \ecvitem[10pt]{Hobbies}{ Chess, Movies, Photography, Watching Sports Channels}

      %\ecvitem[10pt]{Other skills}{Creating pieces of Art and visiting Modern Art galleries. Enjoy all sports particularly cricket, hockey and football. Love to travel and experience different cultures.}

      %\ecvitem[10pt]{Driving licence}{A, B}

        %\ecvsection{ADDITIONAL INFORMATION}
         %
       %\ecvitem{Publications}{`How to do Observations: Borrowing techniques from the Social Sciences to help Participants do Observations in Simulation Exercises' Coyote EU/CoE Partnership Publication, (2002).}

      \end{europecv}
       \end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any MWE to offer?

Comment: MWE stand for ?

Comment: You are an experienced user. → [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: @HarishKumar now check the MWE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hard way ahead. Put this in your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ecvskype}[1]{\def\ecv@skype{#1}}
\renewcommand{\ecvpersonalinfo}[1][20pt]{%
& \tabularnewline[20pt]
\textcolor{torea-bay}{\MakeUppercase{\ecv@infosectionkey}} & \LARGE\ecv@name\tabularnewline[10pt]
\ifx\@empty\ecvdrawpicture &\else
\ecv@beforepic\ecvdrawpicture\ecv@afterpic &
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@address\else
$\begin{array}{@{}l}\includegraphics[width=\ecv@iconwidth]{ic_address}\end{array}$\ecv@address\par\vspace{5pt}
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@mobile\else
$\begin{array}{@{}l}\includegraphics[width=\ecv@iconwidth]{ic_mobile}\end{array}$\ecv@mobile
 \ifx\@empty\ecv@telephone\else\qquad\includegraphics[width=\ecv@iconwidth]{ic_phone_home} \ecv@telephone\fi
\par\vspace{5pt}
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@emailid\else
    $\begin{array}{@{}l}\includegraphics[width=\ecv@iconwidth]{ic_email}\end{array}$
    \ifx\@empty\ecv@emailtext
        \href{mailto:\ecv@emailid}{\foreignlanguage{english}{\ecv@emailid}}
    \else
        \href{mailto:\ecv@emailid}{\ecv@emailtext}
    \fi
    \par\vspace{5pt}
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@homepage\else
$\begin{array}{@{}l}\includegraphics[width=\ecv@iconwidth]{ic_url}\end{array}$\ecv@homepage\par\vspace{5pt}
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@linkedin\else
$\begin{array}{@{}l}\includegraphics[width=\ecv@iconwidth]{ic_linkedin}\end{array}$%
\ecv@linkedin\par\vspace{5pt}
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@skype\else
$\begin{array}{@{}l}\includegraphics[width=\ecv@iconwidth]{skype}\end{array}$%
\ecv@skype\par\vspace{10pt}
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@gender
    \ifx\@empty\ecv@birth
        \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality
            % false false false
        \else
            % false false true
             \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
        \fi
    \else
        %false true
        \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ecv@birthkey} \ecv@birth
        \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality
            % false true false
            \par\vspace{5pt}
        \else
            % false true true
            \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}

        \fi
    \fi
\else
    % true
    \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ecv@genderkey} \ecv@gender
    \ifx\@empty\ecv@birth
        \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality
            % true false false
            \par\vspace{5pt}
        \else
            % true false true
             \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
        \fi
    \else
        %true true
        \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@birthkey} \ecv@birth
        \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality
            % true true false
            \par\vspace{5pt}
        \else
            % true true true
            \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
        \fi
    \fi
\fi

\tabularnewline[#1]
}

\makeatother
```

and download skype icon (say from [this link](https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fs-icons-ubuntu-by-franksouza-/512/skype_protocol.png) and later use

```
\ecvlinkedin{\href{LinkedIn public profile URL}{LinkedIn public profile URL without ``http://''}}
\ecvskype{\href{Skype}{Skype details}}
```

[image]

## Surgical way:

Add these

```
\usepackage{xpatch}        
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ecvskype}[1]{\def\ecv@skype{#1}}

\xpatchcmd{\ecvpersonalinfo}
{\ecv@linkedin\par\vspace{10pt}
\fi}
{\ecv@linkedin\par\vspace{5pt}
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@skype\else
$\begin{array}{@{}l}\includegraphics[width=\ecv@iconwidth]{skype}\end{array}$%
\ecv@skype\par\vspace{10pt}
\fi}
{}
{}
\makeatother
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[helvetica,english,logo,notitle,totpages,utf8]{europecv2013}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.2cm,left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xpatch}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ecvskype}[1]{\def\ecv@skype{#1}}

\xpatchcmd{\ecvpersonalinfo}
{\ecv@linkedin\par\vspace{10pt}
\fi}
{\ecv@linkedin\par\vspace{5pt}
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@skype\else
$\begin{array}{@{}l}\includegraphics[width=\ecv@iconwidth]{skype}\end{array}$%
\ecv@skype\par\vspace{10pt}
\fi}
{}
{}
\makeatother

%[Tutti i campi del CV sono facoltativi. Rimuovere i campi vuoti.]
\ecvname{Replace with First name(s) Surname(s)}
\ecvaddress{Replace with house number, street name, city, postcode, country}
\ecvtelephone[Replace with telephone number]{Replace with mobile number}
\ecvemail{State e-mail address}
\ecvhomepage{\href{Homepage URL}{Homepage URL without ``http://''}}
\ecvlinkedin{\href{LinkedIn public profile URL}{LinkedIn public profile URL without ``http://''}}
\ecvskype{\href{Skype}{Skype details}}
\ecvgender{Enter sex}
\ecvdateofbirth{dd/mm/yyyy}
\ecvnationality{Enter nationality/-ies}

\ecvfootnote{© European Union, 2002-2015 | http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu}
%\ecvbeforepicture{\raggedleft}
%\ecvpicture[width=2.5cm]{file-immagine-eps}
%\ecvafterpicture{\ecvspace{-37mm}}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{europecv}
\ecvpersonalinfo[10pt]

\ecvposition{Job applied for
Position
Preferred kob
Studies applied for}{Replace with job applied for / position / preferred job / studies applied for (delete non relevant headings in left column)}

\ecvsection{Work experience}
%[Add separate entries for each experience. Start from the most recent.]

\ecvworkexperience{Replace with dates (from - to)}{Replace with occupation or position held}{Replace with employer’s name}{Replace with employer’s locality (if relevant, full address and website)}{Replace with main activities and responsibilities}

\ecvsection{Education and training}
%[Add separate entries for each course. Start from the most recent.]

\ecveducation{Replace with dates (from - to)}{Replace with qualification awarded}{Replace with education or training organisation’s name and locality (if relevant, country)}{
Replace with a list of principal subjects covered or skills acquired}{Replace with EQF (or other) level if relevant}

\end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to modify the `.cls` file *which is not a good idea* as your modifications will be overwritten with an update, here is how to jump in to the sea. First save a copy of `europecv2013.cls` and name it `myeuropecv2013.cls`

After line 355, say add these

```
\newcommand*{\ecvlinkedin}[1]{\def\ecv@linkedin{#1}}  %% this line is reference
\newcommand*{\ecvskype}[1]{\def\ecv@skype{#1}}   %% <---add
```

and then add `\ecvlinkedin{}` after line 393. Then in command

```
\providecommand{\ecvpersonalinfo}[1][20pt]{%
```

on line 390, below

```
\ifx\@empty\ecv@linkedin\else
$\begin{array}{@{}l}\includegraphics[width=\ecv@iconwidth]{ic_linkedin}\end{array}$\ecv@linkedin\par\vspace{10pt}
\fi
```

(lines 416-418), add these

```
\ifx\@empty\ecv@skype\else
$\begin{array}{@{}l}\includegraphics[width=\ecv@iconwidth]{skype}\end{array}$%
\ecv@skype\par\vspace{10pt}
\fi
```

BTW change `\ecv@linkedin\par\vspace{10pt}` to `\ecv@linkedin\par\vspace{5pt}`

Then save `myeuropecv2013.cls and use`\documentclass{myeuropecv2013}

Comment: where I put the about code in MAIN file of europass

Comment: @MickyK I have added another shorter method and also the full code at the end. Please see.

Comment: this is good. But it is possible to modify the europecv2013.cls file just give the simple one line command

Comment: @MickyK Why do you want to modify the `.cls` file. Not good. If you insist, I will add those lines to the answer.

Comment: Why `$\begin{array}...\end{array}$` when a simpler `tabular` would do the same? The fact that the original code is doing the same misuse is not an excuse. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I wanted to do the minimal change.

Comment: @HarishKumar it is possible for you to share the myeuropecv2013.cls, because I am trying but it's not working

Comment: @MickyK I am too late. I think I lost the file. Are you trying exactly as I told above? With surgical way, you won't need myeuropecv.cls. Try it please.