# How to add the skype icon in EuropassCV? I am trying hard to add it but it's not working

Tags: cv, europecv

I have implemented the code from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241885) but am still having trouble running my document.  Code example:

```
\documentclass[helvetica,english,logo,notitle,totpages,utf8]{europecv2013}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.2cm,left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ecvname{Name }
\ecvaddress{House No }
\ecvtelephone[+00000000]{+00000000}
\ecvemail{abd@gmail.com}
\ecvlinkedin{\href{http://ae.linkedin.com/pub/abc}{ae.linkedin.com/pub/abc /32/2aa/a83/}}
\ecvgender{Male}
\ecvnationality{name of country}
\ecvdateofbirth{21 January 1974}
\ecvbeforepicture{\ecvspace{-0.8cm}}
\ecvpicture[height=3.5cm, width=3cm]{abc }
%\ecvafterpicture{\ecvspace{4.0cm}}

\ecvfootnote{Â© European Union, 2002-2013 |    http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu}
%\ecvbeforepicture{\raggedleft}
%\ecvpicture[width=2.5cm]{fototessera}
%\ecvafterpicture{\ecvspace{-37mm}}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{europecv}
\ecvpersonalinfo[10pt]

\ecvposition{Job applied for}{ }

\ecvsection{Work experience}

 \ecvworkexperience{September 2009 -- September 2012}{ Research  Assistant}{Abc University}{city}{}

 %\ecvworkexperience{March 2002 -- July 2002}{Internship}{European Commission, Youth Unit, DG Education and Culture}{}

 %\ecvworkexperience{October 2001 â€“ February 2002}{Researcher / Independent Consultant}{Council of Europe, Budapest (Hungary)}{}{}

 \ecvsection{Education and training}

 \ecveducation{2005 -- 2008}{Master of Science }{Abc University,City }{Thesis Title: }{}

 \ecveducation{2001 -- 2005}{Bachelor of Science }{Abc City}{Studies focused }{}

 \ecvsection{Thesis Abstract}
 \ecvitem{Thesis Abstract:}{The thesis describes}

 \ecvsection{Research Interest}
 \ecveducation{}{}{ Computational Fluid Dynamics}{}{}

 \ecvsection{Personal skills}

 \ecvmothertongue[20pt]{English, German}
 \ecvlanguageheader
 \ecvlanguage{English}{C1}{C2}{C1}{C2}{C1}
 %\ecvlastlanguage{German}{A2}{A2}{A2}{A2}{A2}
 \ecvlanguagefooter[10pt]

 %\ecvitem[10pt]{Communication skills}{}


 \ecvitem[10pt]{Computer skills}{\LaTeX, Tikz, jPicEdt, Matlab, Mathematica, C/C++, \LaTeX Draw, Mayura Draw, MS Office.}

 \ecvitem[10pt]{Hobbies}{ Chess, Movies, Photography, Watching Sports Channels}

  %\ecvitem[10pt]{Other skills}{Creating pieces of Art and visiting Modern Art galleries. Enjoy all sports particularly cricket, hockey and football. Love to travel and experience different cultures.}

  %\ecvitem[10pt]{Driving licence}{A, B}

    %\ecvsection{ADDITIONAL INFORMATION}
     %
   %\ecvitem{Publications}{`How to do Observations: Borrowing techniques from the Social Sciences to help Participants do Observations in Simulation Exercises' Coyote EU/CoE Partnership Publication, (2002).}

   \end{europecv}
   \end{document}
```

When I run the document, I receive the error `LaTeX Error: File 'skype' not found.`  How can I fix it?

Comment: What error messages are you seeing?  Would you please trim your code sample down to a minimal example that shows the problem?

Comment: @cxw \ecvpersonalinfo[10pt] and LatEx Error: File 'skype' not found. I just want to add the skype icon in europass CV

Comment: Thanks!  Please pardon my ignorance - I don't know the details of europecv.  Are you using the latest from https://github.com/leinardi/europecv2013 or a different version?  I looked at that and the older docs at http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/europecv/europecv.pdf and it's not clear to me - which command is supposed to be adding the Skype icon?  `\ecvtelephone`?  `\ecvpicture`?

Comment: @cxw check this How to add the Skype ICON in Europass CV? u will find the code

Comment: This MWE does not in any way use the solution from the other question and does not even contain the word `skype`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure `skype.png` is in the same directory as your `.tex` file if you are using `pdflatex`.  (For DVI output, convert to an EPS and put skype.eps in the directory with your TeX file.)  See [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics#Including_graphics) for an explanation.
2. Add `\graphicspath{{./}{<PATH>/}}` just after `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, where `<PATH>` is the location where your `.cls` file is stored.  That will tell LaTeX to look in the current directory and that directory for images.  See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139401) for more.

Comment: skype and tex file directory is same.

Comment: Double-check that you said `\includegraphics` and not just `\include` in the `\ecv@skype` command.  The post you linked to has a lot of detail, and any typos might cause problems.  Did you edit the `.cls` file (not recommended) or use the preamble or `xpatch` options?

Comment: $\begin{array}{@{}l}\includegraphics[width=\ecv@iconwidth]{skype.eps}\end{array}$%
\ecv@skype\par\vspace{10pt}. I can't edit the .cls file

Comment: First, remove the `.eps` from the `\includegraphics` command.  If that doesn't work, try rendering your EPS to a PNG using GIMP (http://www.gimp.org) or ghostscript and see if that helps.

Comment: Micky, any luck?  It also occurs to me - if you can't edit the `.cls` file, where are the other icon files (e.g., `ic_email.png`)?  Are they in the same directory as your LaTeX source file, or in a separate directory with the `.cls` file?

Comment: still working but still given me the error. Yes they all in same directory