# European CV (resume). How can i add the section "Language(s) Certificates"?

Tags: labels

I'm writing the european cv (resume), with a code that is  a latex code of the offical version of the european cv format.

I need to add the subsection "Language(s) Certificates" (see the picture), but unfortunately online I didn't find the solution of my problem.[image]

I've paste a copy of the latex code. Thank you!

```
\documentclass[helvetica,openbib,totpages]{europecv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.27cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{url}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{phv} % Uses Helvetica instead of fixed width font

\ecvname{Surname, Name}
\ecvfootername{Name Surname}
\ecvaddress{House number, street name, postcode, city, country}
\ecvtelephone[(Remove if not relevant)]{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvfax{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvemail{\url{email@address.com} (Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvnationality{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvdateofbirth{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvgender{(Remove if not relevant)}
%\ecvpicture[width=2cm]{mypicture}
\ecvfootnote{For more information go to \url{http://europass.cedefop.eu.int}\\
\textcopyright~European Communities, 2003.}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}


\begin{europecv}
\ecvpersonalinfo[5pt]
\ecvitem{\large\textbf{Desired employment/ Occupational~field}}{\large\textbf{(Remove if not relevant)}}

\ecvsection{Work experience}
\ecvitem{Dates}{Add separate entries for each relevant post occupied, starting from the most recent. (Remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem{Occupation or position held}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Main activities and responsibilities}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Name and address of employer}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Type of business or sector}{\ldots}

\ecvsection{Education and training}

\ecvitem{Dates}{Add separate entries for each relevant course you have completed, starting from the most recent. (Remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem{Title of qualification awarded}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Principal subjects/Occupational skills covered}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Name and type of organization providing education and training}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Level in national or international classification\footnote{If appropriate.}}{\ldots}

\ecvsection{Personal skills and~competences}

\ecvmothertongue[5pt]{Specify mother tongue}
\ecvitem{\large Other language(s)}{}
\ecvlanguageheader{(*)}
\ecvlanguage{Language}{}{}{}{}{}
\ecvlanguage{Language}{}{}{}{}{}
\ecvlanguagefooter[10pt]{(*)}

\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Social skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Organisational skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Technical skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Computer skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Artistic skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Other skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem{\large Driving licence(s)}{State here whether you hold a driving licence and if so for which categories of vehicle. (Remove if not relevant).}

\ecvsection{Additional information}
\ecvitem[10pt]{}{Include here any other information that may be relevant, for example contact persons, references, etc. (Remove heading if not relevant).}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{publications}
\ecvitem{}{\textbf{Publications}}
\ecvitem{}{\bibentry{pub1}}
\ecvitem[10pt]{}{\bibentry{pub2}}
\ecvitem{}{\textbf{Personal interests}}
\ecvitem{}{\ldots}

\ecvsection{Annexes}
\ecvitem{}{List any item attached to the CV}
\end{europecv}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for example can you add the following lines:

```
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Language(s) certificates}{}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large \textbf{English}}{Blafasel, Total score: 333, date: 2015-10-21}
```

to have a larger fontsize for the words Languages certificates and English, `\textbf{English}` for bold word English.

At last I think better would be to use the normal size:

```
\ecvitem[10pt]{Language(s) certificates}{}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\textbf{English}}{Blafasel, Total score: 333, date: 2015-10-21}
```

You have to play with `[10pt]` to get the space you want to the next line.

complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[helvetica,openbib,totpages]{europecv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.27cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{url}

\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{phv} % Uses Helvetica instead of fixed width font

\ecvname{Surname, Name}
\ecvfootername{Name Surname}
\ecvaddress{House number, street name, postcode, city, country}
\ecvtelephone[(Remove if not relevant)]{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvfax{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvemail{\url{email@address.com} (Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvnationality{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvdateofbirth{(Remove if not relevant)}
\ecvgender{(Remove if not relevant)}
%\ecvpicture[width=2cm]{mypicture}
\ecvfootnote{For more information go to \url{http://europass.cedefop.eu.int}\\
\textcopyright~European Communities, 2003.}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}


\begin{europecv}
\ecvpersonalinfo[5pt]
\ecvitem{\large\textbf{Desired employment/ Occupational~field}}{\large\textbf{(Remove if not relevant)}}

\ecvsection{Work experience}
\ecvitem{Dates}{Add separate entries for each relevant post occupied, starting from the most recent. (Remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem{Occupation or position held}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Main activities and responsibilities}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Name and address of employer}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Type of business or sector}{\ldots}

\ecvsection{Education and training}

\ecvitem{Dates}{Add separate entries for each relevant course you have completed, starting from the most recent. (Remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem{Title of qualification awarded}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Principal subjects/Occupational skills covered}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Name and type of organization providing education and training}{\ldots}
\ecvitem{Level in national or international classification\footnote{If appropriate.}}{\ldots}

\ecvsection{Personal skills and~competences}

\ecvmothertongue[5pt]{Specify mother tongue}
\ecvitem{\large Other language(s)}{}
\ecvlanguageheader{(*)}
\ecvlanguage{English}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}
\ecvlanguage{Deutsch}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}
\ecvlanguage{Language}{}{}{}{}{}
\ecvlanguagefooter[10pt]{(*)}

\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Language(s) certificates}{}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large \textbf{English}}{Blafasel, Total score: 333, date: 2015-10-21}

\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Social skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Organisational skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Technical skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Computer skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Artistic skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Other skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem{\large Driving licence(s)}{State here whether you hold a driving licence and if so for which categories of vehicle. (Remove if not relevant).}

\ecvsection{Additional information}
\ecvitem[10pt]{}{Include here any other information that may be relevant, for example contact persons, references, etc. (Remove heading if not relevant).}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{publications}
\ecvitem{}{\textbf{Publications}}
\ecvitem{}{\bibentry{pub1}}
\ecvitem[10pt]{}{\bibentry{pub2}}
\ecvitem{}{\textbf{Personal interests}}
\ecvitem{}{\ldots}

\ecvsection{Annexes}
\ecvitem{}{List any item attached to the CV}
\end{europecv}


\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: part of cv with added language certificate]

BTW: You use an old version.  The current version of the europass cv is from 2013 (document class `europecv2013`).  With the same addition shown above you get:

[image: result with europecv2013]

Comment: How i add the skype Icon

Comment: I try alot but it's not working

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241885/how-to-add-the-skype-icon-in-europass-cv check this link

Comment: Any suggestion on how can I add result for the IELTS test like the table you have shown in the image above? In IELTS test, except Reading, Listening and Writing there is only one Speaking score unlike Spoken interaction and Spoken production in your above example. Thank you

Comment: @Jack Please ask a new question!