# How to add the place of birth in Europass CV?

Tags: cv, europecv

Command `\evcdateofbirth` is for the Date of Birth.

Is there any option for Place Of Birth? Command `\ecvplaceofbirth` does not work.

Similar to this question:
[How to add the Skype ICON in Europass CV?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241885/how-to-add-the-skype-icon-in-europass-cv)

Comment: [Welcome](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/34551)! Please, be more precise in your question. I guess you are using the class [`europasscv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/europasscv), but are you willing to modify the class to get your result? Also, a [small example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/34551) doesn't hurt. Could you please copy-and-paste the _revelant part_ of your preamble, so that the document compile and shows what you already done?

Comment: Is there any news here?

Answer (score 1):

The given class `europecv2013` follows the official europass cv document **not knowing** a place of birth.  As I commented I think it is not a very good idea to change that, but well ...

First you need to add the following two lines to your code:

```
\newcommand*{\ecvplaceofbirth}[1]{\def\ecv@placebirth{#1}} % <===================
\newcommand*{\ecv@placebirthkey}{Place of Birth}
```

That defines a variable `\ecvplaceofbirth` you can use in your cv ...

Now the problem is to integrate this new information into the current cv.  Therefore we have to change several lines in the original code to be able to build the needed line depended of the given datas:

```
\ecvgender{Male}
\ecvnationality{name of country}
\ecvdateofbirth{21 January 1974}
\ecvplaceofbirth{Place}
```

The relevant part of code are the following lines where I added the place of birth, which results in several `\ifx\@empty\ecv@placebirth`:

```
\ifx\@empty\ecv@gender
  \ifx\@empty\ecv@birth
    \ifx\@empty\ecv@placebirth
      \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality                                       %false false false false
      \else                                                             %false false false true
        \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
      \fi% \ecv@nationality
    \else                                                               %false false true ?
      \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ecv@placebirthkey} \ecv@placebirth \par\vspace{5pt}
      \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality                                       %false false true false
      \else                                                             %false false true true
        \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
      \fi% \ecv@nationality
    \fi% \ecv@placebirth
  \else                                                                 %false true ?     ?
    \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ecv@birthkey} \ecv@birth
    \ifx\@empty\ecv@placebirth                                          %false true false ?
      \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality                                       %false true false false
        \par\vspace{5pt}
      \else                                                             %false true false true
        \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
      \fi% \ecv@nationality
    \else                                                               %false true true ?
      \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@placebirthkey} \ecv@placebirth
      \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality                                       %false true true false
        \par\vspace{5pt}
      \else                                                             %false true true true
        \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
      \fi% \ecv@nationality
    \fi% \ecv@placebirth
  \fi% \ecv@birth
\else                                                                   %true ?     ?     ?
  \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ecv@genderkey} \ecv@gender
  \ifx\@empty\ecv@birth                                                 %true false ?     ?
    \ifx\@empty\ecv@placebirth                                          %true false false ?
      \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality                                       %true false false false
        \par\vspace{5pt}
      \else                                                             %true false false true
        \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
      \fi% \ecv@nationality
    \else                                                               %true true true ? 
      \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@placebirthkey} \ecv@placebirth
      \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality                                       %true true true false
        \par\vspace{5pt}
      \else                                                             %true true true true
       \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
      \fi% \ecv@nationality
    \fi
  \else                                                                 %true true ?    ?
    \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@birthkey} \ecv@birth
    \ifx\@empty\ecv@placebirth                                          %true true false ?
      \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality                                       %true true false false
        \par\vspace{5pt}
      \else                                                             %true true false true
        \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
      \fi% \ecv@nationality
    \else                                                               %true true true ?
      \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@placebirthkey} \ecv@placebirth
      \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality                                       %true true true false
        \par\vspace{5pt}
      \else                                                             %true true true true
        \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
      \fi% \ecv@nationality
    \fi% \ecv@placebirth
  \fi% \ecv@birth
\fi% \ecv@gender
```

So with the following complete MWE (I added the new code to the cv `.tex` file to avoid to change the original file `europecv2013.cls`):

```
\documentclass[helvetica,english,logo,notitle,totpages,utf8]{europecv2013}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.2cm,left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ecvplaceofbirth}[1]{\def\ecv@placebirth{#1}} % <===================
\newcommand*{\ecv@placebirthkey}{Place of Birth}

\renewcommand{\ecvpersonalinfo}[1][20pt]{%
& \tabularnewline[20pt]
\textcolor{torea-bay}{\MakeUppercase{\ecv@infosectionkey}} & \LARGE\ecv@name\tabularnewline[10pt]
\ifx\@empty\ecvdrawpicture &\else
\ecv@beforepic\ecvdrawpicture\ecv@afterpic &
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@address\else
$\begin{array}{@{}l}\includegraphics[width=\ecv@iconwidth]{ic_address}\end{array}$\ecv@address\par\vspace{5pt}
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@mobile\else
$\begin{array}{@{}l}\includegraphics[width=\ecv@iconwidth]{ic_mobile}\end{array}$\ecv@mobile
 \ifx\@empty\ecv@telephone\else\qquad\includegraphics[width=\ecv@iconwidth]{ic_phone_home} \ecv@telephone\fi
\par\vspace{5pt}
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@emailid\else
    $\begin{array}{@{}l}\includegraphics[width=\ecv@iconwidth]{ic_email}\end{array}$
    \ifx\@empty\ecv@emailtext
        \href{mailto:\ecv@emailid}{\foreignlanguage{english}{\ecv@emailid}}
    \else
        \href{mailto:\ecv@emailid}{\ecv@emailtext}
    \fi
    \par\vspace{5pt}
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@homepage\else
$\begin{array}{@{}l}\includegraphics[width=\ecv@iconwidth]{ic_url}\end{array}$\ecv@homepage\par\vspace{5pt}
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@linkedin\else
$\begin{array}{@{}l}\includegraphics[width=\ecv@iconwidth]{ic_linkedin}\end{array}$\ecv@linkedin\par\vspace{10pt}
\fi
\ifx\@empty\ecv@gender
  \ifx\@empty\ecv@birth
    \ifx\@empty\ecv@placebirth
      \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality                                       %false false false false
      \else                                                             %false false false true
        \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
      \fi% \ecv@nationality
    \else                                                               %false false true ?
      \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ecv@placebirthkey} \ecv@placebirth \par\vspace{5pt}
      \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality                                       %false false true false
      \else                                                             %false false true true
        \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
      \fi% \ecv@nationality
    \fi% \ecv@placebirth
  \else                                                                 %false true ?     ?
    \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ecv@birthkey} \ecv@birth
    \ifx\@empty\ecv@placebirth                                          %false true false ?
      \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality                                       %false true false false
        \par\vspace{5pt}
      \else                                                             %false true false true
        \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
      \fi% \ecv@nationality
    \else                                                               %false true true ?
      \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@placebirthkey} \ecv@placebirth
      \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality                                       %false true true false
        \par\vspace{5pt}
      \else                                                             %false true true true
        \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
      \fi% \ecv@nationality
    \fi% \ecv@placebirth
  \fi% \ecv@birth
\else                                                                   %true ?     ?     ?
  \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ecv@genderkey} \ecv@gender
  \ifx\@empty\ecv@birth                                                 %true false ?     ?
    \ifx\@empty\ecv@placebirth                                          %true false false ?
      \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality                                       %true false false false
        \par\vspace{5pt}
      \else                                                             %true false false true
        \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
      \fi% \ecv@nationality
    \else                                                               %true true true ? 
      \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@placebirthkey} \ecv@placebirth
      \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality                                       %true true true false
        \par\vspace{5pt}
      \else                                                             %true true true true
       \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
      \fi% \ecv@nationality
    \fi
  \else                                                                 %true true ?    ?
    \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@birthkey} \ecv@birth
    \ifx\@empty\ecv@placebirth                                          %true true false ?
      \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality                                       %true true false false
        \par\vspace{5pt}
      \else                                                             %true true false true
        \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
      \fi% \ecv@nationality
    \else                                                               %true true true ?
      \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@placebirthkey} \ecv@placebirth
      \ifx\@empty\ecv@nationality                                       %true true true false
        \par\vspace{5pt}
      \else                                                             %true true true true
        \textcolor{curious-blue}{\ | \ecv@nationalitykey} \ecv@nationality \par\vspace{5pt}
      \fi% \ecv@nationality
    \fi% \ecv@placebirth
  \fi% \ecv@birth
\fi% \ecv@gender

\tabularnewline[#1]
}
\makeatother


\ecvname{Name }
\ecvaddress{House No }
\ecvtelephone[+00000000]{+00000000}
\ecvemail{abd@gmail.com}
\ecvlinkedin{\href{http://ae.linkedin.com/pub/abc}{ae.linkedin.com/pub/abc /32/2aa/a83/}}
\ecvgender{Male}
\ecvnationality{name of country}
\ecvdateofbirth{21 January 1974}
\ecvplaceofbirth{Place}
\ecvbeforepicture{\ecvspace{-0.8cm}}
\ecvpicture[height=3.5cm, width=3cm]{example-image-a}
%\ecvafterpicture{\ecvspace{4.0cm}}

\ecvfootnote{© European Union, 2002-2013 |    http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu}
%\ecvbeforepicture{\raggedleft}
%\ecvpicture[width=2.5cm]{fototessera}
%\ecvafterpicture{\ecvspace{-37mm}}


\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{europecv}
\ecvpersonalinfo[10pt]

\ecvposition{Job applied for}{ }

\ecvsection{Work experience}
 \ecvworkexperience{September 2009 -- September 2012}{ Research  Assistant}{Abc University}{city}{}

\ecvsection{Education and training}
 \ecveducation{2005 -- 2008}{Master of Science }{Abc University,City }{Thesis Title: }{}
 \ecveducation{2001 -- 2005}{Bachelor of Science }{Abc City}{Studies focused }{}

\ecvsection{Thesis Abstract}
 \ecvitem{Thesis Abstract:}{The thesis describes}

\ecvsection{Research Interest}
 \ecveducation{}{}{ Computational Fluid Dynamics}{}{}

\ecvsection{Personal skills}
 \ecvmothertongue[20pt]{English, German}
 \ecvlanguageheader
 \ecvlanguage{English}{C1}{C2}{C1}{C2}{C1}
 %\ecvlastlanguage{German}{A2}{A2}{A2}{A2}{A2}
 \ecvlanguagefooter[10pt]
 %\ecvitem[10pt]{Communication skills}{}
 \ecvitem[10pt]{Computer skills}{\LaTeX, Tikz, jPicEdt, Matlab, Mathematica, C/C++, \LaTeX Draw, Mayura Draw, MS Office.}
 \ecvitem[10pt]{Hobbies}{ Chess, Movies, Photography, Watching Sports Channels}

\end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

and the resulting pdf:

[image: top part of first page]