# How can I add skype adress in my europasscv?

Tags: preamble, addresses, europasscv

I am using this code to build my cv. I would like to add my skype adress with its symbol. How can I do ?

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX program = pdflatex
% !TEX spellcheck = en_GB

\documentclass[english,a4paper]{europasscv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber,autolang=hyphen,sorting=none,style=numeric,maxbibnames=99,doi=false,isbn=false,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{europasscv-bibliography}





\bibliography{europasscv_example}
% in the bibliography, mark all occurrences in bold:
\ecvbibhighlight{Smith}{Katie}{K.}

\ecvname{Name Surname}
\ecvaddress{Address}
\ecvmobile{numbers}
\ecvtelephone{numbers}
%\ecvworkphone{+353 999 888 777}
\ecvemail{e-mail}
%\ecvhomepage{www.myhomepage.com www.another-homepage.com}
\ecvgithubpage{GitHubPage}

% \ecvgitlabpage{www.gitlab.com/smith}
% \ecvlinkedinpage{www.linkedin.com/in/katie-smith}
% \ecvorcid[label, link]{0000-0000-0000-0000}
%\ecvim{AOL Messenger}{katie.smith}
%\ecvim{Google Talk}{ksmith}

% \ecvgender{Female}
\ecvdateofbirth{date}
\ecvnationality{Nationality}

% \ecvpicture[width=3.8cm]{picture.jpg}

% \date{}

\begin{document}
  \begin{europasscv}

  \ecvpersonalinfo
  \ecvbigitem{Job applied for}{Job}


  
  


    

\end{europasscv}
  
\end{document}
```

This prints the following cv preamble:
[image]

I searched here, however what I can find is this code in the link that does not work for me [How to add the Skype ICON in Europass CV?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241885/how-to-add-the-skype-icon-in-europass-cv)

Do you have suggestions about how to modify the code that I reported in order to add my skype adress ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I said in my post, no @C.F.G.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: As I said in my post, no @StefanPinnow .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is my poor try:

First download this [skype icon](https://icons8.com/icons/set/skype) as pdf and rename it to `skype_europass_icon.pdf` and move it to your current tex project folder. then add the following before `\begin{document}`

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ecvskypepage}[1]{
\raisebox{-2\lineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.4cm]{skype_europass_icon.pdf}}\hspace{0.2mm} {\fontseries{m}\selectfont \processlinks{#1}} \newline}
\makeatother
```

It is not perfect but using `\ecvskypepage{your skype}` **after** `\begin{document}`
will print what you want but using this it is not aligned to other links.

### UPDATE (CORRECT OUTPUT):

First download this [skype icon](https://icons8.com/icons/set/skype) as pdf and rename it to `skype_europass_icon.pdf` and move it to your current tex project folder.
(NOTE: Do not use `\href` inside this new defined command)

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX program = pdflatex
% !TEX spellcheck = en_GB

\documentclass[english,a4paper]{europasscv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber,autolang=hyphen,sorting=none,style=numeric,maxbibnames=99,doi=false,isbn=false,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{europasscv-bibliography}

\bibliography{europasscv_example}
% in the bibliography, mark all occurrences in bold:
\ecvbibhighlight{Smith}{Katie}{K.}

\ecvname{Name Surname}
\ecvaddress{Address}
\ecvmobile{numbers}
\ecvtelephone{numbers}
%\ecvworkphone{+353 999 888 777}
\ecvemail{e-mail}
%\ecvhomepage{www.myhomepage.com www.another-homepage.com}
\ecvgithubpage{GitHubPage}


\usepackage{xpatch}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ecvskypepage}[1]{\def\ecv@skypepage{#1}}

\xpatchcmd{\ecvpersonalinfo}
{\ifx\@empty\ecv@linkedinpage\else
        \raisebox{-2\lineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.4cm]{icons/linkedin_europass_icon.pdf}}\hspace{0.2mm} {\fontseries{m}\selectfont \processlinks{\ecv@linkedinpage}} \newline
      \fi}
{\ifx\@empty\ecv@linkedinpage\else
        \raisebox{-2\lineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.4cm]{icons/linkedin_europass_icon.pdf}}\hspace{0.2mm} {\fontseries{m}\selectfont \processlinks{\ecv@linkedinpage}} \newline
      \fi
      \ifx\@empty\ecv@skypepage\else
        \raisebox{-2\lineskip}{\includegraphics[width=0.4cm]{skype_europass_icon.pdf}}\hspace{0.2mm} {\fontseries{m}\selectfont \processlinks{\ecv@skypepage}} \newline
      \fi}
{}
{}
\makeatother

\ecvlinkedinpage{LinkedIn public profile URL}
\ecvskypepage{Skype}
%\ecvgithubpage{GitHubPage}{SkypePage}
% \ecvlinkedinpage{www.linkedin.com/in/katie-smith}
% \ecvorcid[label, link]{0000-0000-0000-0000}
%\ecvim{AOL Messenger}{katie.smith}
%\ecvim{Google Talk}{ksmith}

% \ecvgender{Female}
\ecvdateofbirth{date}
\ecvnationality{Nationality}

% \ecvpicture[width=3.8cm]{picture.jpg}

% \date{}

\begin{document}
  \begin{europasscv}

  \ecvpersonalinfo
\end{europasscv}
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It appears up to personal information but it is already something that is good. Thank you !

Comment: Thanks for the update !